# SSRS display all Months in a year with no data

Tags: date, reporting-services

Is it possible to return all months between 2 dates; Start date and End Date in SSRS for a matrix. My current code is resulting in the following for a rolling 12-month period.

```
    Sept '16  Dec '16   Jan '17  Feb '17  Mar '17  Apr '17  May'17  Jun '17 Aug '17
Shift     
Day           
Evening
Night
```

I would like the results to be for between the start date and end date for 12 months.

```
     Sept '16 Oct'16  Nov'16 Dec'16 Jan'17 Feb'17 Mar '17  Apr '17  May'17  Jun '17 Aug '17
Shift     
Day           
Evening
Night
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a date table of some kind. At the most basic you'll need a list of numbers 1-12. Then you can build your dates based on that and the current month. Once you have a list of dates you can then LEFT JOIN to your main data, this will ensure that each month is represented, even if there is not data.

You'll probably want to have this as a permanent table but this is just an in-line version for the sake of illustration..

```
DECLARE @m TABLE (MonthNum int)
INSERT INTO @m
VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)

DECLARE @curMonth int = Month(getdate())
DECLARE @curYear int = Year(getdate())

SELECT 
*
, DATEADD(year, (CASE WHEN MonthNum > @curMonth THEN (@curYear-1) ELSE @curYear END)-1900, DATEADD(month, MonthNum-1, DATEADD(day, 0, 0))) as Last12Months
 FROM @m
```

This will give you one date per month from 2016-09-01 to 2017-08-01

Depending on the data you are joining to, you might need to format the dates to match your data. Post your data if you are struggling and I can give a more focused answer.